# paintComponent method is called only once

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to write simple programm which draws circle when mouse is dragged, but the paintComponent method is called only once (after start).

In this class class I have few methods which paints circle when mouse is dragged.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class PaintingField extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
    int x,y;

    public PaintingField(){
        setPreferredSize((new Dimension(500,500)));
        x = -1;
        y = -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println("painting");
        if(x == -1 || y == -1)
            return;

        g.drawOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Here I create an object of my paiting class and add it to my main Frame class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER;

public class PatternCreator extends JFrame {

    JButton save = new JButton("save");
    JButton load = new JButton("load");
    JButton clear = new JButton("clear");
    JButton chooseFolder = new JButton("choose folder");
    JTextField path = new JTextField("");
    PaintingField paintingField = new PaintingField();

    public PatternCreator(){
        createLayout();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        addMouseMotionListener(new PaintingField());
    }

    public void createLayout(){
        JPanel pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(groupLayout);

        groupLayout.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);
        groupLayout.setAutoCreateGaps(true);

        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(CENTER)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(save)
                        .addComponent(load)
                        .addComponent(clear)
                        .addComponent(chooseFolder))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(paintingField,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(path))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(save)
                        .addComponent(load)
                        .addComponent(clear)
                        .addComponent(chooseFolder))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(paintingField,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup()
                        .addComponent(path))
        );

        pack();
    }

}
```

And the main method.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TextRecognition {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            PatternCreator patternCreator = new PatternCreator();
        });
    }

}
```

The mouseDragged method is called, because printing position of cursor so repaint is called too. Can somebody explain me why paintComponent method is not called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering a new instance of `PaintingField` as the mouse listener, instead of your previously created object.

Replace :

```
addMouseMotionListener(new PaintingField());
```

With :

```
addMouseMotionListener(paintingField);
```

Also your `paintComponent` method should call the parent method, to ensure that everything gets cleared correctly.

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

As a last note, to avoid components coordinates problems, you should rather register the mouse listener on the `PaintingField` panel directly.

So try putting the following in the `PaintingField` 's constructor

```
addMouseMotionListener(this);
```

And remove `addMouseMotionListener(paintingField)` from `PatternCreator` .

Answer (score 1):

The `paintingField` you’re using for the actual frame and for the mouse listeners aren’t the same. That means, when you call the repaint in the `paintingField` method of the mouseListener, you’re actually repainting a different, invisible frame. To fix it you should use the same object. So change the mouseListener line to:

```
addMouseMotionListener(paintingField);
```